# bootstrap: more than one modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using two bootstrap modals on my site:

```
       <!---- modal 1 ---->
       <div id="send-pm" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="send-pm" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Send Foobar a PM</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>One fine body…</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
        </div>

        <!---- modal 2 --->
        <div id="post-comment" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-2" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="post-comment" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Post a Comment</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>One fine body…</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
        </div>
```

They are triggered by:

```
<a href="#send-pm" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-small"> Send PM </a>
<a href="#post-comment" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-small"> Post Comment </a>
```

However, only the first one shows up. My second one `post-comment` is not showing up. There are no JS errors on console.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't support modal-on-modal stacking.  If you want functionality like that, you'll need to [use another library.](http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/)

Comment: You are just missing closing divs. The reason PSCoders answer works is because it properly terminates the modal div. If you just fix up your closing div for the modal-footer it will work just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/jesus_tesh/jS9Vt/1/

Comment: @Jay Is Your issue resolved?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To make both of them work. Just put them in separate containers instead of one after the another.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jS9Vt/)

```
<a href="#send-pm" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-small"> Send PM </a>
<a href="#post-comment" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-small"> Post Comment</a>

    <!---- modal 2 --->
    <div id="post-comment" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-2" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="post-comment" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Post a Comment</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>One fine body…</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <!---- modal 1 ---->
        <div id="send-pm" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="send-pm" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 id="myModalLabel">Send Foobar a PM</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>One fine body…</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```